# Run HUnit without output

Tags: haskell, hunit

I have a Test:

```
test1 = TestCase (assertEqual "Bla" 2 (add1 1))
```

And want to run it in another Haskell programm without automatic I/O output which

```
runTestTT test1
```

would create. I tried

```
runTestText (putTextToHandle stderr False) test1
```

but this will still create output. Is there a way (maybe another Handle instead of stderr/stdout) to stop the test from creating output?

I would like to just get the IO Counts to use them at another place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `PutText` doesn't produce any output:

```
foo = runTestText (PutText go 0) test1
  where go :: String -> Bool -> Int -> IO Int
        go s b i = return 0
```

Here `foo` has type `IO (Counts, Int)`, so you get the counts with just:

```
do (counts, _) <- foo
   ...
```